# How do I fix Postgres so it will start after an abrupt shutdown?

Tags: postgresql, recovery

Due to a sudden power outage, the Postgres server running on my local machine shut down abruptly. After rebooting, I tried to restart Postgres and I get this error:

**`$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data restart`**

```
pg_ctl: PID file "/usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid" does not exist
Is server running?
starting server anyway
server starting
$:/usr/local/pgsql/data$ LOG:  database system shutdown was interrupted at 2009-02-28 21:06:16 
LOG:  checkpoint record is at 2/8FD6F8D0
LOG:  redo record is at 2/8FD6F8D0; undo record is at 0/0; shutdown FALSE
LOG:  next transaction ID: 0/1888104; next OID: 1711752
LOG:  next MultiXactId: 2; next MultiXactOffset: 3
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  redo starts at 2/8FD6F918
LOG:  record with zero length at 2/8FFD94A8
LOG:  redo done at 2/8FFD9480
LOG:  could not fsync segment 0 of relation 1663/1707047/1707304: No such file or directory
FATAL:  storage sync failed on magnetic disk: No such file or directory
LOG:  startup process (PID 5465) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

There is no `postmaster.pid` file in the data directory.  What possibly could be the reason for this sort of behavior and of course what is the way out?

Comment: What postgres version are you using, and what is the type of the filesystem for `/usr/local/pgsql/data`?

Comment: Just so you know, chances are you might have to restore from backup.  But before doing that, please share with us your Postgres version (in v8.1.5 and v8.1.6 IIRC there was a bug triggering this error during recovery) and filesystem type (you might want to change that before the next outage.)

Comment: hint: "restart", you're telling PostgreSQL that it is running and needs to be restarted. It's not running, thus there is no process id (.pid) file.

Answer (score 28):

You'd need to [pg_resetxlog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-pgresetxlog.html). Your database can be in an inconsistent state after this though, so dump it with `pg_dumpall`, recreate and import back.

A cause for this could be:

- You have not turned off hardware
  write cache on disk, which often
  prevents the OS from making sure data is written before it reports successful write to application. Check with

  `hdparm -I /dev/sda`

  If it shows "*" before "Write cache" then this could be the case. [Source of PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v8.3.6/) has a program src/tools/fsync/test_fsync.c, which tests speed of syncing data with disk. Run it - if it reports all times shorter than, say, 3 seconds than your disk is lying to OS - on a 7500rpm disks a test of 1000 writes to the same place would need at least 8 seconds to complete (1000/(7500rpm/60s)) as it can only write once per route. You'd need to edit this test_fsync.c if your database is on another disk than /var/tmp partition - change

  `#define FSYNC_FILENAME  "/var/tmp/test_fsync.out"`

  to

  `#define FSYNC_FILENAME  "/usr/local/pgsql/data/test_fsync.out"`
- Your disk is failing and has a bad block, check with [badblocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badblocks).
- You have a bad RAM, check with [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) for at least 8 hours.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I had moved the DB, but i decided to give your option a try. It has worked and the db is restored. pg_resetxlog has done the trick.

Comment: This problem can also happen when an Windows OS Upgrade occoures - Not only does the postmaster become inaccessable, but permissions on the data folder and the service may dissapear. pg_resetxlog solves the first problem.

Comment: This can also simply happen with an incredibly overloaded storage subsystem on linux.

Comment: Had this after a (very mean) test of overloading the disk subsystem on linux.

Answer (score 6):

Reading a few similar messages in the archives of the PostgreSQL
mailing list ("storage sync failed on magnetic disk: No such file or
directory") seems to indicate that there is a very serious hardware
trouble, much worse than a simple power failure. You may have to prepare yourself to restore from backups.

Comment: Ant P,Vlad Romascanu and bortzmeyer - Thank you for all your commennts. I have figured out that the hard disk has got corrupted because of the power spike. I have to move postgres to another machine.

Comment: @bortzmeyer: fsck told me that there were errors in the hard disk. so i was misled into believing that the db cannot be restored but the pg_resetxlog command has done the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Had db corruption too, my actions

```
docker run -it --rm -v /path/to/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:10.3 bash
su - postgres
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_resetwal -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -f
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and I was about to dump, reinstall and import from db dump (a really painfull process), however I just tried this as the last resource and it worked!

`brew services start postgresql`

Then I restarted and that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Run start instead of restart.
Execute the below command:

```
$pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data start
```

Comment: I get "pg_ctl: directory "/usr/local/pgsql/data" does not exist" error when I run this

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem a couple of times, when my laptop turned off unexpectedly, when on very low battery while running PSQL in the background.

My solution after searching all over was, `Hard delete and Reinstall`, then import data from db dump.

Steps for Mac with brew to uninstall and reinstall psql 9.6

```
brew uninstall postgresql@9.6
rm -rf rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6
rm -rf .psql.local .psql_history .psqlrc.local l.psqlrc .pgpass

brew install postgresql@9.6

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

brew services start postgresql@9.6

createuser -s postgres
createuser {ENTER_YOUR_USER_HERE} --interactive
```

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, a stop + start instead of a restart worked for me. In a Docker environment this would be:

```
docker stop <container_name>
docker start <container_name>
```

or when using Docker Compose:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose start
```