# GitLab HA with Kubernetes and Gluster

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, gitlab, glusterfs

I currently have GitLab omnibus setup on Docker. I plan to have HA for the same by adding it to Kubernetes and have persistence using Gluster. I have played around configuring Kubernetes with Gluster. Now it's time to bring GitLab into Kubernetes. GitLab uses PostgreSQL as the default db.

My query is that to implement HA, should i
a) split GitLab into GitLab application and PostgreSQL container, and then run both (Application and DB) in their own cluster of pods i.e., separate *deployments* of replicas of GitLab app and PostgreSQL?
OR
b) keep using the omnibus installer and just have replicas of this single, standalone container?

Does it really make any difference whether
1) writes happen to a db cluster exposed via service to the GitLab app
OR
2) writes happening directly to the omnibus GitLab container (which has db within itself)

Just want to make sure that i don't unnecessarily end up making the setup complex. Having GitLab in Kubernetes along with Gluster already makes things a little complex. So does splitting app and db makes sense or just the omnibus setup will suffice? Concerned about concurrent writes to db.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/kubernetes/gitlab_omnibus.html#introduction **you should use dedicated Redis and PostgreSQL** HA clusters. Option b) and 1)

For less downtime better to use **PostgreSQL master-slave** cluster (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/different-replication-solutions.html) and **Redis Cluster master-slave** (https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial). "Note that the minimal (Redis) cluster that works as expected requires to contain at least three master nodes".

If you will use only GlusterFS to bring failover to PostgreSQL, you can get some errors requires manual repair when one DB instance crashes and another brings up. Like this: [How do I fix Postgres so it will start after an abrupt shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598200/how-do-i-fix-postgres-so-it-will-start-after-an-abrupt-shutdown)