# Ubuntu restarting postgresql services

Tags: postgresql

When I am trying to restart **PostgreSQL** services then I am getting error:

> Restarting PostgreSQL: pg_ctl: PID file "/home/pgsql/postmaster.pid" does not exist

Is the server running?

Comment: What is the command you're using to restart the server?  Can you see it running with `sudo ps aux`?  This question may be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/510697/missing-postgresql-postmaster-pid

Comment: i have used **sudo service postgresql restart**

Comment: What happens if you `stop` and then `start`, instead of `restart`.

Comment: **sudo service postgresql stop** giving me the same "postmaster.pid does not exist" error

Comment: Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598200/how-do-i-fix-postgres-so-it-will-start-after-an-abrupt-shutdown

Comment: **sudo ps aux** not showing it running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix Postgres so it will start after an abrupt shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598200/how-do-i-fix-postgres-so-it-will-start-after-an-abrupt-shutdown)

Comment: my file system is like */home/pgsql*, and there is no data directory

Comment: Ok...how is that relevant?

Comment: thanku all, i have solved the problem , actually pgsql directory had wrong ownership and permission. I changed its ownership to postgres and set permission to 700 and restarted the system. And it worked..